# Redirect to other page on click on Google Maps marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular

I am developing my first AngularJS2 app with a Google map. I want to forward the user to another page (using AngularJS Routing) when clicking a marker.

At the moment nothing happens. I think it's a general problem of understanding the events in AngularJS...

```
angular.module('starter.controllers').controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.413192, 8.033106);    

  var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  var myLatlnggg = new google.maps.LatLng(55.413192, 8.033106);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlnggg,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  $scope.marker = marker;

  google.maps.event.addListener($scope.marker, 'click', function(){
      $location.path( '/spot' );
  });

})
```

Comment: Is the marker click event working? Should use `$apply()` for events that are outside of angular context

Comment: @charlietfl thank you! this helps! Would be create, if you post it as answer so I can mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For events that occur outside angular context use `$scope.$apply()` to advise angular of changes

```
google.maps.event.addListener($scope.marker, 'click', function(){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
      $location.path( '/spot' );
  });     
});
```